# Python: search playlists on youtube

Tags: python, gdata-python-client

Is there any way to search playlists on youtube using gdata-python-client? As for documentation it is impossible, but may be there are some workarounds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The you tube python API seems to have a way of searching the playlists matching specific term.
As per the documentation, API has the capability to retrieve a list of playlists matching a user-specified search term.

- http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlist_search.html

[Edit : Curl output]

I just used curl and the API seems to work fine.

```
~ $ curl 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/snippets?q=soccer&start-index=11&max-results=10&v=2'
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' gd:etag='W/&quot;C0cHRX85eCp7ImA9Wx5VEko.&quot;'><id>tag:youtube.com,2008:playlists:snippets</id><updated>2010-10-05T09:30:34.120Z</updated><category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#playlistLink'/><title>YouTube Playlists matching query: soccer</title><logo>http://www.youtube.com/img/pic_youtubelogo_123x63.gif</logo><link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/snippets?v=2'/><link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/snippets/batch?v=2'/><link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/snippets?q=soccer&amp;start-index=11&amp;max-results=10&amp;v=2'/><link rel='service' type='application/atomsvc+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/snippets?alt=atom-service&amp;v=2'/><link rel='previous' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/snippets?q=soccer&amp;start-index=1&amp;max-results=10&amp;v=2'/><link rel='next' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/snippets?q=soccer&amp;start-index=21&amp;max-results=10&amp;v=2'/><author><name>YouTube</name><uri>http://www.youtube.com/</uri></author><generator version='2.0' uri='http://gdata.youtube.com/'>YouTube data API</generator><openSearch:totalResults>1241773</openSearch:totalResults><openSearch:startIndex>11</openSearch:startIndex><openSearch:itemsPerPage>10</openSearch:itemsPerPage></feed>~ $
```

Comment: That's not python specific API, but general one. BTW http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/snippets?q=soccer&start-index=11&max-results=10&v=2 - empty feed, where am I wrong?

Comment: @Vladimir: I used curl command and it seems to fetch the information.

Comment: You can open it via browser with same result, but there is no playlist entries nor any references to it besides totalResults...

Comment: just checked today your link and it works. So it seems that was youtube problem. Thanks a lot.